# Регулярные выражения C# сравнение строки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть массив с именами (не важно какими). Есть строка `2016070100_2016080100_005.zip`, которую надо выделить из остальных по соответствию маске. Сейчас у меня это выглядит так

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\*.zip");
```

но нужно чтобы искал не только **.zip**, но и **0_2016**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@".+?0_2016.+\.zip");
```

---

Кроме того, можно обойтись без регулярных выражений, просто проверив вхождение `0_2016` и `.zip`:

```
if (str.Contains("0_2016") && str.EndsWith(".zip")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Очень помог.